Problem of finding the invariant factors and elementary divisors of a quotient group.
$\mathbf{The \ Problem \ is}:$ Let $G:= \Bbb{Z}_9\times \Bbb{Z}_9\times \Bbb{Z}_9$ and $H:= \langle(6,6,6)\rangle.$ Find the invariant factors and elementary divisors of the quotient group $G/H.$
$\mathbf{My \ Approach}:$ Note, $H=\{(0,0,0),(3,3,3),(6,6,6)\}.$ Then $|G/H|=3^6/3=3^5.$ Now, I was trying to find the isomorphism type of $G/H$ using the Fundamental Theorem for finitely generated abelian groups. Clearly, $G/H$ is not a cyclic group, so $G/H\not\cong {\Bbb{Z}}_{3^5}.$ Let $A:={\Bbb{Z}}_{81}\times {\Bbb{Z}}_3$ and $B:={\Bbb{Z}}_{27}\times {\Bbb{Z}}_9.$ Now, I was trying to compare the number of order $3$ elements of $G/H$ with that of $A$ and $B.$ Firstly, the set of all order $3$ elements of $A$ is $\text{Ord}_3(A)=\{(p,q)\in A\mid p\in \{0,27,54\}, q\in \{0,1,2\}, (p,q)\neq (0,0)\}.$ Similarly, $\text{Ord}_3(B)=\{(p,q)\in B\mid p\in \{0,9,18\}, q\in \{0,3,6\}, (p,q)\neq (0,0)\}.$ As $\text{Ord}_3(G/H)=\{(a,b,c)\in G/H\mid a,b,c\in \{0,3,6\}, (a,b,c)\neq (0,0,0)\}\cup \{(x,x,x)\in G/H\mid x\in \{1,2,4,5,7,8\}\},$ thus $G/H\not\cong A$ and $G/H\not\cong B.$ Let, $C:= {{\Bbb{Z}}_3}^{\times 5}$ and here $\text{Ord}_3(C)$ has $3^5-1$ elements of order $3$ implying $G/H\not\cong C.$ For $D:={{\Bbb{Z}}_3}^{\times 3}\times {\Bbb{Z}}_9,$ $\text{Ord}_3(D)$ has $3^4-1$ elements which again implies $G/H\not\cong D.$ The last two remaining groups(upto isomorphism) are $E:= {\Bbb{Z}}_{27}\times {\Bbb{Z}}_3\times {\Bbb{Z}}_3$ and $F:= {\Bbb{Z}}_3\times {\Bbb{Z}}_9\times {\Bbb{Z}}_9.$ But calculating $\text{Ord}_3(E)$ and $\text{Ord}_3(F)$ both gives $26$ elements but then the list becomes exhausted. I think I am making some foolish mistake. Can you please provide some hints? Thanks in advance for that?

The standard method of solving problems of this type is by computing the Smith Normal Form of an associated matrix over the integers, in this case the $4 \times 3$ matrix with rows $(9\ 0\ 0)$, $(0\ 9\ 0)$, $(0\ 0\ 9)$, $(6\ 6\ 6)$. The calculation is straightforward in this example, and results in a matrix with non-zero diagonal entries $3,9,9$.

Note that the order of every element of $G$ is a divisor of $9$, and hence the order of every element of $G/H$ is also a divisor of $9$. That rules out many of the possible isomorphism types for $G/H$ right away, and in particular is enough to finish off your approach.
